# JWT Authentication with Airflow API

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, airflow

I am trying to implement a token based authentication as part of triggering an airflow dag. Is there way we can add JWT authentication to generate an access_token to trigger the API? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Our authentication service returns a `JSON` response like this :

```json
{
    "clientToken": "322e8df6-0597-479e-984d-db6d8705ee66"
}
```

Here is my sample code in airflow 2.1 using `SimpleHttpOperator` and `XCOM` variable passing mechanism to overcome this problem :

```py
    get_token = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_token',
        method='POST',
        http_conn_id='http_service',
        data=json.dumps( {
            "username": "user_name",
            "password": "n46r4A83"
        }),
        endpoint='/authenticate',
        dag=dag,
        headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        },
        response_filter=lambda response: response.json()['clientToken'],
    )

    
    get_cities = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_cities',
        method='GET',
        http_conn_id='http_service',
        endpoint='/cities?dsCode=120',
        dag=dag,
        headers = {
        'X-CLIENT-TOKEN':'{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="get_token") }}'
        }
        # response_filter=lambda response: response.json()['clientToken'],
    )

    get_token >> get_cities
```

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: It suggest a way to use JWT tokens by calling `get_token` function.

Comment: For an arbitrary external HTTP service that already implements JWT auth, not for Airflow's own API.